# How to re-apply data filter programmatically?

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

I need to re-apply filter when any data on the worksheet changes. Excel requires to do this manually. How I can re-apply filter programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to remove auto-filter and re-apply it thanks to this kind of VBA Code (you can probably adapt it to VSTO?):

```
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim filterArray()
Dim currentFiltRange As String

Sub ChangeFilters()

Set w = Worksheets("Crew")
With w.AutoFilter
    currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
    With .Filters
        ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then
                        filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End With

w.AutoFilterMode = False
w.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="S"

End Sub
```

Code found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210085.aspx)

[EDIT] You can also find some valuable information in this thread: [Reordering Excel Table Columns with Filters Intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970758/reordering-excel-table-columns-with-filters-intact) (look at the comments)

Answer (score 0):

When the treeview is used in the filter of a date field then its criteria cannot be determined. That's why you will need a temporary custom view to re-apply the filter. See [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59917).